# LaTeX: Greek fonts available?

Tags: fonts, greek

I am using LaTeX and the default font that it is providing. I was wondering if there are any other fonts available I can have. My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

%\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2} %For chapter/section not being visible in text
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}


\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
```

What can I do to try other fonts too? The default one I'm getting is a little bit weird.

Comment: For other font packages, cf. [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). For greek fonts, cf. the [Greek](http://www.ctan.org/topic/greek) topic at CTAN.

Comment: If you are willing to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (needed for `fontspec`) you can use any open type font that you have on your system; The Greek Font Society might be a good place to look: http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/gr_about.html

Comment: What if I stick with Latex? Can I have just a couple of fonts available with it?

Comment: Is there a big difference if I decide to use XeLaTex

Comment: I don't think so. It runs slower, and there are a few areas (e.g., IIRC, the `microtype` package) where it is not fully supported, but for someone working in unicode who needs easy access to "non-standard" fonts, I think it's an obvious choice. But I'm not an expert (in that or Greek fonts!) which is why this is a comment not an answer. There are proper experts here who may be able to comment. You might like to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex.

Comment: If you look for fonts supporting polytonic Greek, then see [Fonts for PolyTonic Greek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127222).

Comment: All questions tagged with tags [tag:fonts] and [tag:greek], not that much in the moment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts+greek.

Answer (score 7):

You have the `GFS font collection` (8 fonts), developped by the Greek Font Society (whence the name) that exist in opentype and type 1 formats and can be used by (pdf)LaTeX as well as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. They also have latin letters, except 2 of them:  `Porson` and `Baskerville`, but there is LaTeX support for (latin) Baskerville.

At least for a part of them, there is some support for maths (I didn't check for all). For instance, GFS Artemisia relies on tx fonts, except of course for Greek letters. From [this page](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/gfs.html) of the `LaTeX Catalogue`, you will have access to all the details and font samples that you might want.

Using them is simple: if you're using (pdf)LaTeX, just  write `\usepackage{artemisia}` in your preamble. If you're  using Xe/LuaLaTeX, it's just

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}
```

Comment: Thanks..!! Any lead on how I can use them ?

Comment: The details are in the docs (not fully, however). I'll add a word about that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Bernard..!! I'm using (pdf)LaTex and I just added \usepackage{artemisia} and I got an error: file artemisia.sty not found. I installed it from the Synaptic package manager, closed Kile and compiled again but got the same error again. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How did you install it? Via TLMGr (if you use TeX Live) or MiKTeX Package Manager ? or by hand?

Comment: Well... neither. Just the Operating system's Package manager. It was available in the repositories.

Comment: I suppose your system didn't refresh the TeX file names database nor the installed type1 fonst database (psfonts.map ). First run texhash from the command line, then updmap. This should settle the problem if the files were correctly installed. If it doesn't work, you should redo the installation via the TeX Live package manager (TLPmgr), which is btw the recommended way.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here... I installed the whole tex live through my Synaptic Package Manager and when I run "tlmgr update --list" I get the following message: "No command 'tlmgr' found". Any way to handle this? Seems like there's not a TLPmgr at all here? Don't know...

Comment: Probably… As far as I know, some Linux distributions do not really install the whole of TeX Live. Maybe uninstall what was installed through Synaptic Package Manager and download  TeX Live. But before such extreme solution: did you run  texhash` and `updmap` afterwards?

Comment: Yeah I did.. and it seemed to work..I don't get it.. I mean the commands run but no effect on the compiling. still it can't find the .sty

Comment: Stefanos -- I know this is a year late -- you need to use `xelatex` not `pdflatex` on the command line for this to work.

Comment: `\usepackage{gfsartemisia}` worked for me!