# Spaces in font names

Tags: xetex, greek

I have an updated TeX Live distribution.

Following [Fonts for PolyTonic Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127222/fonts-for-polytonic-greek) I copied the code exactly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    
    
\newcommand\test[1]{%
  #1\\{\fontspec{#1}Βίβλος γενέσεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ υἱοῦ Δαυὶδ υἱοῦ Ἀβραάμ.}
  \par\medskip}
    
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
\begin{document}
    
\test{CMU Serif}
\test{EB Garamond}
\test{GFS Artemisia}
\test{GFS Baskerville}
\test{GFS Bodoni}
\test{GFS Complutum}
\test{GFS Didot}
\test{GFS Olga}
\test{GFS Porson}
\test{GFS Solomos}
\test{Junicode}
\test{Linux Libertine O}
\test{Old Standard}
\end{document}
```

into `c.tex` and then did `xelatex c`. This returned the following error:

> /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)kpathsea:make_tex:
> Invalid fontname `CMU Serif', contains ' '
>
> fontspec error: "font-not-found"  l.14 \test{CMU Serif}

Thus its first objection is to a space in a font name. How can that linked example work with a whole list of fonts with spaces in their names? And it also appears that no font whose name contains the strings "Serif" and "CMU" is part of TeX Live 2013:

> find /usr/local/texlive -type f | egrep -i  serif | egrep -i cmu

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't have an up-to-date TeX distribution, because you're running TeX Live 2013. In order to be able to call the font by their PostScript names, you need to make them visibl to your system. How to do it depends on your operating system.

Comment: I have run "sudo tlmgr update --self" and "sudo tlmgr update --all". What else do I need to do to update TeXLive on this computer?

Comment: You cannot update TeX Live 2013 any further.  The current release is TeX Live 2014, and you can't directly upgrade from 2013 to 2014 (or, later this year, to 2015).  You must reinstall TeX Live each year if you want to have access to `tlmgr`.  Alternatively, you can update things manually.  If your needs are simple, this is not too onerous. (I used to do this.)

Comment: `find` is no good in any case. It is not searching by filename - of course the names of the files do not have spaces in them! - but by the postscript name. You can see what the name of a given opentype font is, for example, using `otfinfo -i <path-to-font>` but to use it, `fontconfig` must also know about it.

Answer (score 5):

The error is not really due to a space in the font name, but rather in the fact that the font “CMU Serif” is not available as a system font.

On a GNU/Linux box with TeX Live, the simplest way to make all fonts in TeX Live available to the system is to copy the pointers to the font directories to `/etc/fonts/conf.d` and do `fc-cache`:

```
sudo cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

Just tried on a GNU/Linux box and here's the output:

[image]

Comment: I had a problem with FontAwesome and your answer saved me. thanks man

Comment: In my Ubuntu Linux, the file by the name `texlive-fontconfig.conf` does not exist anywhere under  `/var`.  Any suggestion?

Comment: there is only one directory: `/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map` that doesn't contain any `.conf` files

Comment: @YanKingYin You might try to download it from the TeX Live repository

Comment: @egreg thanks, but I found a solution by just using the real file names, (see my answer),,.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is really going on, I have TexLive installed on both laptop and desktop computers.  In one installation the font name with spaces works but not in the other.  I'm too tired to check their versions or how they differ.

The solution for me is simply to:

```
fc-list | grep "the font name"
```

and look at its **real** file name.  Use that instead.